# ERROR in my UDPClient Program

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I am trying to run a basic UDPCLient-Server program.
When i am compile my UDPClient program its causing the below ERROR.
Though my Server one compiled successfully.

Can someone guide what's going wrong?

ERROR:

```
UDPClient.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                                new DatagramPacket(m,m.length(),aHost,serverPort);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable d of type byte[]
1 error
```

My Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class UDPClient{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                // args give message contents and server hostname
                DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
                try {
                        aSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                        byte[] m = args[0].getBytes();
                        InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getByName(args[1]);
                        int serverPort = 6789;
                        DatagramPacket request =
                                new DatagramPacket(m,m.length(),aHost,serverPort);
                        aSocket.send(request);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                        aSocket.receive(reply);
                        System.out.println("Reply: " + new String(reply.getData()));
                }
                catch (SocketException e){
                        System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                finally { if (aSocket != null) aSocket.close(); }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your tags are incorrect, `udpclient`is specific to .Net. And I can't find the mentioned line anywhere in your code.

Comment: You replaced d with m.

Comment: I was trying to change the variable and see, but it didn't work though. I re-posted the ERROR .

Comment: Replace m.length() with m.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of an array in Java is **not** retrieved through a method (`m.length()`); it's just a field (`m.length`).  Thus it should be `m.length`, *not* `m.length()`.